# Plone 4.0.5 and photo gallery

Tags: gallery, photo, plone

I would like to have a photo gallery and tried "collective.plonetruegallery" which is nice. Im just curious, are there any other good alternatives that is recommended (it takes a lot of time to test all of them).

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done [collective.gallery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.gallery). You can find demos [here](http://toutpt.makina-corpus.org/add-ons/collective.gallery/gallery):

You should try it, it is used in production, quite easy to customize (all controls are binded to css ids) It is well tested. Let me know if you have any troubles with it.

Answer (score 1):

I really like to use [collective.prettyphoto](http://plone.org/products/collective.prettyphoto). Installs cleanly, works as expected and also looks nice.

Comment: Thanks zupo, Ill try it out. Nikolaj G.